# Connect Spark Streaming to Spark Batch automatically

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, lambda-architecture

I'm receiving streaming data from Kafka, which I'm reading as a dataframe with Structured Spark Streaming.

The problem is that I need to perform multiple aggregations on the same column and non-time-based window operations with that results.

AFAIK that's still not possible in Spark Structured Streaming, so I want to start a Spark batch job triggered after some time.

How could I achive that? Is there any way to start a python script like with spark submit?

Comment: Could you add an example of your code? At least for me, it's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This should be possible in Spark Streaming, not sure it's in Structured Streaming, though.

Comment: I have a spark application that performs calculus with data taken from a database, that is updated a lot of times, that's why I want to use spark streaming, to launch the spark job if there is new data instead of relaunching the spark job application periodically.

Now, I'm listening to my database changes, so when a new value is added, my kafka producer perform a query and send it to the spark consumer. The point is that there are a lot of operations that are not possible in spark streaming, so I want to launch a spark job from spark streaming like using spark-submit. 
Is it possible?

Comment: I'm using Spark Structured Streaming because the spark job uses spark libraries based on Spark Dataframes

Comment: Could you draft an example of the process you want? I can see how to model it in spark streaming. The verbal description is too open for interpretation. So, a minimal streaming job and the spark actions you would
 like to trigger afterward.

Comment: ok, I simple action not available in spark streaming could be groupByInterval method of a flint dataframe [Flint Dataframe](https://github.com/twosigma/flint/blob/master/python/ts/flint/dataframe.py). It's not a question of using this method on the streamed data because there are too many other functions

Comment: I can give you another simple operation that I want to perform

`df_res = df.withColumn('deviation', (func.abs(df.values - df.agg(func.avg(df.values)).collect()[0][0] ))/ df.agg(func.stddev(df.values)).collect()[0][0] )
`
where func is pyspark.sql.functions

This action is allowed in spark, but in spark structured streaming is not, because of the collect and the multiple aggregation